# Blender 2.82 smoke sim not baking

Tags: baking, smoke-simulation

I did preview with cache type:replay , looks fine in viewport(rendered and solid). But whenever i bake modular or final , it does baking and end result it nothing. No smoke, also i use adaptive domain , that does nothing either(it basically ignored all baking it did). Can anyone point me to where problem might be?